# How to query an external MS Access DB from an Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle, ms-access, oracle11g, odbc

How to configure Oracle to be able to query a MS Access database (.accdb) that is lcoated in the same server (localhost)?

Which steps to follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version of Oracle: 11g -> 11.2.0.1.0

Version of Windows: Windows Server 2008

Steps to complete:

1. Create System DSN with Microsoft Access Driver
2. Modify *listener.ora* file
3. Create the file *initaccess.ora*
4. Modify *tnsnames.ora* file
5. Restart listener
6. Check connection with access database
7. Create the DB Link in Oracle

**STEP 1: Create system DSN**

First go to ODBC Data Source Administrator click on System DSN tab. The create a DSN with the following parameter (you can choose the name link that you prefer but then you need to keep the same name all over the process).
[image: Link creation]

In our case:

- Driver: Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)
- Name: **access**
- Description: (doesn't matter)
- Database -> Select -> (Select the .accdb or .mdb database)
- Save the configuration
- Make sure you see this listed once you save it:

  *Name - Driver*

  *access - Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)*

**STEP 2: Modify listener.ora file**

Let's locate the file. In our case:

- **E:\app\Administrador\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN**

We need to add the following text at the end. By the way, look at I posted as 'oracle_home' the directory in C: drive. That's because I had more than one directory related to Oracle, and I still don't understand it but worked in my case. Maybe in yours there's only one.

Parameters you need to modify:

**In first block:**

- SID_NAME: name chosen in the step above. The name of the dsn created ('access' in our case)
- ORACLE_HOME: Home directory of Oracle
- PROGRAM = dg4odbc (I think that from Oracle 11g and beyond, 'dg4odbc' is mandatory.

**In second block:**

- HOST: The name of the hostname (not sure if localhost' or an IP address are supported, but I guess they are)

---

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC=
      (SID_NAME = access)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Administrador\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = dg4odbc)
    )
  )
```

---

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host_name)(PORT = 1521))   
    )
  )
```

---

Make sure there is no space before 'SID_LIST_LISTENER' or 'LISTENER' in the file you modify:

[image: listener.ora file]

**STEP 3: Create the initaccess.ora file**

Go to:

- E:\app\Administrador\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\hs\admin

There, make a copy of 'initdg4odbc.ora' file (I deleted it after I made a copy). Add the following text to the file:

```
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = access 
HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL = 0
```

- **HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO**: Here we write the name of the link created in the ODBC source tool in the first step, so it's 'access'
- **HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL**: Leave it with a 0

[image]

**STEP 4: Modify tnsnames.ora file:**

Let's locate the file. In our case:

- **E:\app\Administrador\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN**

Parameters to modify:

- HOST: hostname of the server
- SID: this is the name of the 'initaccess.ora' file BUT taking away the 'init' part and '.ora' file extension: then 'access'.
- (HS=OK) = don't forget this.

---

```
access =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host_name) (PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = access)
    )
    (HS=OK)
  )
```

---

Be sure that you don't leave spaces before the 'access =' parameter.

[image: tnsnames.ora file]

**STEP 5: Restart the listener**

- Open a command line terminal
- Go to: *C:\app\Administrador\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN*
- Stop the listener

  - **C:\app\Administrador\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN>LSNRCTL.EXE stop**
  - You should see a message saying it was successfull
- Restart the listener

  - **C:\app\Administrador\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN>LSNRCTL.EXE start**
  - You should see a message saying it was successfull
  - You should also see, (in the output, when restarting the server) a message talking about the 'access' service we just added

> > El servicio "access" tiene 1 instancia(s).
> >
> > La instancia "access", con estado UNKNOWN, tiene 1 manejador(es) para este ser
> >     vicio...
> >
> > El comando ha terminado correctamente

**STEP 6: Test connection with the access database**

- Open a command line terminal
- Go to: *C:\app\Administrador\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN*
- Run **tnsping.exe** (as argument, pass the name of the link: 'access'):
- **C:\app\Administrador\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN>tnsping.exe access**
- You should see a message saying it was correctly run and displaying the delay in msecs

---

```
TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 06-JUN-2
014 11:04:35

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Archivos de parßmetros utilizados:
E:\app\Administrador\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Adaptador TNSNAMES utilizado para resolver el alias
Intentando contactar con (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = CUPCA
KE) (PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = access)) (HS=OK))
Realizado correctamente (20 mseg)
```

**STEP 7: Create the DB Link in Oracle and query the Ms Access database:**

**Create the DB Link (always as **sys**):**

```
CREATE public DATABASE LINK accessdblink USING 'access';
```

* 'access': Same name as in *tnsnames.ora* -> **'access = '**

**Query the database:**

```
SELECT * FROM table_name@accessdblink;
```